# How can you hide a sub-property in the Xceed PropertyGrid for WPF?

Tags: c#, wpftoolkit, propertygrid, xceed

We are currently using the Xceed `PropertyGrid` control to display our application's printing settings.  Here is an excerpt from the class we are using:

```
public class ReportOptions {

    public FontOptions FontOptions { get; } = new FontOptions();
    public PageOptions PageOptions { get; } = new PageOptions();
}

[ExpandableObject]
public class FontOptions {
    public string FontName        { get; set; } = "Times New Roman";
    public double HeadingFontSize { get; set; } = 14.0;
    public double BodyFontSize    { get; set; } = 12.0;
}

[ExpandableObject]
public class PageOptions{

    [ExpandableObject]
    public Thickness Margins { get; set; } = new Thickness(0.5, 1.0, 0.5, 1.0);

    [ExpandableObject]
    public Size      Size    { get; set; } = new Size(8.5,11.0);
}
```

The issue we are having is the `Size` class has a read-only `IsEmpty` property which we would like to hide in the `PropertyGrid`.

[image]

Since we are using the auto-generated properties for the grid, and since we don't 'own' the `Size` class, we're not sure how to decorate that property to hide it.

We tried using `PreparePropertyItem` but the `PropertyItem.IsVisible` is read-only.

So how can we hide that property without having to manually define all properties? (Again, this is just a small excerpt of the actual class.

Answer (score 1):

You need the Browsable(false) attribute to hide something from the PropertyGrid.  If you need to set the attribute at runtime, you may want to look into something like `DynamicTypeDescriptor`